# Changes made at RowDatabound event being cleared or malfunction when postback occurs in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I've a gridview which requires sub title rows or a kind of header rows after certain rows. I achieved that by managing the gridview rows  at RowDatabound event as follows.

```
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            If e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "0" Then
               e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(0)
               e.Row.Cells(0).ColumnSpan = 2
            End If
        End If
```

This is working fine without any problem. But when ever any postback occurs that changes I did on the databound even gets cleared or the gridview rows changes to its actual form. I mean in the code above I removed the first cell and spcified a column span for the second cell as 2. But after the postback the deleted cell comes back. Am not getting an idea why this is happening

Comment: How you are binding your GridView??

Comment: @FlopScientist Using the basic method. Fetch to a datatable dt and set the dt as the datasource for the gridview.

Comment: Can you show that code also, and show gridview markup too